# column counterpart to mysql_fetch_array() in PHP

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and looking for some help.

I read a column of data from a table in a database and send the data to a dropdown menu in the form of an array.

Now, the function mysql_fetch_array() converts a row of data into an array. I tried using the same function on a column with improper results.

Is there a function that similarly converts a column of data into an array?

Comment: *"I tried using the same function on a column with improper results."* - **Define: "Improper results".** - *"Is there a function that similarly converts a column of data into an array?"* - `foreach`? `print_r()`? You'll need to elaborate on your question with an example and/or some code.

Comment: The code you must show.

Comment: You could perhaps use array_column() if you have PHP >= 5.5; or array_map() in earlier versions of PHP.... but show your current code

Answer (score 0):

You could simple iterate over the result(-rows) and get your column array if you like:

```
   $columnArrays = array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
     foreach ($row AS $key=>$value){
       if (isset($columnArrays[$key]))
         $columnArrays[$key][] = $value; //add to existing array
       else
         $columnArrays[$key] = array($value); //create new array
     }  
   }
```

Now you have all `id`s (depending on the column name) in `$columnArrays["id"]` - all names in `$columnArrays["name"]` and so on.